No ground to connect to for light/fan switch
This house was built in '65 with original wiring. There are no ground wires available to connect lights and exhaust fan for my bathroom. I added a yellow 12/2 cable for my vanity light with a ground wire but there is no ground to connect it to. What are my options?
My outlets are grounded and I've added a GFCI to my bathroom. This house is all daisy-chained together, so the GFCI I added only feeds to my north bedroom lights. The south bedroom lights feed into my bathroom lights and exhaust fan. I can't find an outlet in my house that feeds into the bathroom.
Can I run a ground wire to the gfci I currently have? Maybe switch out the plastic box for a metal one and then pigtail all my switches to it?





Ground is for your safety only.  Stuff on the ceiling/high on a wall and mainly plastic, ground usually does not do much.  Newer code allows you to run a separate ground wire to a good ground or panel.  Can also maybe use GFCI protection(outlet/breaker) for added safety.

New bathroom circuits must have GFCI protection.  Older circuits it is highly recommended to add GFCI protection in bathrooms, near kitchen sinks/water.

If your outlets are grounded, run a ground wire from one of them to your bathroom GFCI and the switch box you show, so you can at least ground those switches and your vanity light. Using a metal box will do nothing, you just need an actual equipment ground wire which will be electrically connected to the neutral bar in your service equipment.
